# Programmatically change ultrawide monitor resolution without stretching

Tags: c#, resolution, monitor

I'm trying to write a little C# application to change between ultrawide resolution and 1920 x 1080.

I've been following this guide successfully: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36664/Changing-Display-Settings-Programmatically

And I have it changing between the resolutions. However, when switching to 1920 x 1080 I get a stretched view instead of a centered view on the monitor resolution.

I'm not seeing the appropriate flag in DEVMODE. Anyone know what settings I'm missing to center rather than stretch a monitor resolution?

Comment: Windows 10. Again, the calls work in general. It looks like dmDisplayFixedOutput is what I want but it doesn't seem to work the way I expect it to.

Comment: I would also say that when I change my monitor resolution within Windows manually, it DOES center the 1920x1080 space. So I know it's possible.

Comment: @Micky I'd love to have a more modern API instead. Are you aware of one?

Comment: @Micky Right, this is the point of this post. Again, dmDisplayFixedOutput looks like what I want but does not work.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce.**  I downloaded; compiled and used the code from the CodeProject article and it worked fine on my Windows 10 box. No _"stretching"_

Comment: @Micky I'm interested if you enumerate your window options, do all the resolutions show the different flags for dmDisplayFixedOutput? On my monitor on the resolutions at hand, only stretch is available. However, it works from Windows as I said before.